# Spark dataframe join showing unexpected results - 0 rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark-1.6.0, I want to join 2 dataframe, they showed in YARN log like following.

df_train_raw

df_user_clicks_info

I have tried to inner join them with code:

```cs
val df_tmp_tmp_0 = df_train_raw.join(df_user_clicks_info, Seq("subscriberid"))

df_tmp_tmp_0.show()
```

And the results I got was exactly nothing! OMG!

```
+------------+--------+-----+------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|subscriberid|objectid|label|subscriberid|user_clicks_avg_everyday_a_week|user_clicks_sum_time_1_9_a_week|user_clicks_sum_time_9_14_a_week|user_clicks_sum_time_14_17_a_week|user_clicks_sum_time_17_19_a_week|user_clicks_sum_time_19_23_a_week|user_clicks_sum_time_23_1_a_week|user_clicks_avg_everyday_weekday|user_clicks_sum_time_1_9_weekday|user_clicks_sum_time_9_14_weekday|user_clicks_sum_time_14_17_weekday|user_clicks_sum_time_17_19_weekday|user_clicks_sum_time_19_23_weekday|user_clicks_sum_time_23_1_weekday|user_clicks_avg_everyday_weekdend|user_clicks_sum_time_1_9_weekdend|user_clicks_sum_time_9_14_weekdend|user_clicks_sum_time_14_17_weekdend|user_clicks_sum_time_17_19_weekdend|user_clicks_sum_time_19_23_weekdend|user_clicks_sum_time_23_1_weekdend|
+------------+--------+-----+------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
+------------+--------+-----+------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

I don't know why? It seems nothing wrong here? Hope some help, please~ Thanks~

---

After the 2 friends advice about space, I'd have a another try:

```
df_train_raw
————————————

+------------+-----------+-----+
|subscriberid|   objectid|label|
+------------+-----------+-----+
|   104752237|11029932485|    0|
|   105246837|11029932485|    0|
|   105517237|11029932485|    0|
|   108917037|11030797988|    0|
|   108917037|11029648595|    0|
|   109901037|11029648595|    0|
|   105517237|11030720502|    0|
|   105246837|11029986502|    0|
|   104752237|11029191717|    0|
|   105246837|11029191717|    0|
|   105517237|11029191717|    0|
|   109901037|11030138623|    0|
|   105517237|11014105538|    0|
|   105517237|11014105543|    0|
|   105517237|11016478156|    0|
|   105517237|11023285357|    0|
|   105246837|11026067980|    0|
|   105246837|11030797988|    0|
|   108917037|11029932485|    0|
|   109901037|11029932485|    0|
+------------+-----------+-----+
only showing top 20 rows

————————————

root
 |-- subscriberid: long (nullable = true)
 |-- objectid: long (nullable = true)
 |-- label: integer (nullable = true)
```

and print the "subscriberid" column, this showed not the space case.

```
df_train_raw.select("subscriberid").take(20).foreach(println)
```

the result

```
[104752237]
[105246837]
[105517237]
[108917037]
[108917037]
[109901037]
[105517237]
[105246837]
[104752237]
[105246837]
[105517237]
[109901037]
[105517237]
[105517237]
[105517237]
[105517237]
[105246837]
[105246837]
[108917037]
[109901037]
```

And fot the df_user_clicks_info

```
+------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|subscriberid|user_clicks_avg_everyday_a_week|user_clicks_sum_time_1_9_a_week|user_clicks_sum_time_9_14_a_week|user_clicks_sum_time_14_17_a_week|user_clicks_sum_time_17_19_a_week|user_clicks_sum_time_19_23_a_week|user_clicks_sum_time_23_1_a_week|user_clicks_avg_everyday_weekday|user_clicks_sum_time_1_9_weekday|user_clicks_sum_time_9_14_weekday|user_clicks_sum_time_14_17_weekday|user_clicks_sum_time_17_19_weekday|user_clicks_sum_time_19_23_weekday|user_clicks_sum_time_23_1_weekday|user_clicks_avg_everyday_weekdend|user_clicks_sum_time_1_9_weekdend|user_clicks_sum_time_9_14_weekdend|user_clicks_sum_time_14_17_weekdend|user_clicks_sum_time_17_19_weekdend|user_clicks_sum_time_19_23_weekdend|user_clicks_sum_time_23_1_weekdend|
+------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|   104752237|                           1.71|                              0|                               0|                                0|                                4|                                4|                               4|                             0.8|                               0|                                0|                                 0|                                 0|                                 4|                                0|                              4.0|                                0|                                 0|                                  0|                                  4|                                  0|                                 4|
|   105517237|                          17.14|                             12|                              36|                               12|                                0|                               60|                               0|                             9.6|                               0|                                0|                                 0|                                 0|                                48|                                0|                             36.0|                               12|                                36|                                 12|                                  0|                                 12|                                 0|
|   109901037|                           2.14|                              0|                               3|                                3|                                6|                                3|                               0|                             2.4|                               0|                                0|                                 3|                                 6|                                 3|                                0|                              1.5|                                0|                                 3|                                  0|                                  0|                                  0|                                 0|
|   105246837|                            8.0|                              8|                               0|                                0|                               16|                               32|                               0|                             8.0|                               8|                                0|                                 0|                                 8|                                24|                                0|                              8.0|                                0|                                 0|                                  0|                                  8|                                  8|                                 0|
+------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------+

————————————

root
 |-- subscriberid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_clicks_avg_everyday_a_week: double (nullable = false)
 |-- user_clicks_sum_time_1_9_a_week: long (nullable = false)
 |-- user_clicks_sum_time_9_14_a_week: long (nullable = false)
 |-- user_clicks_sum_time_14_17_a_week: long (nullable = false)
 |-- user_clicks_sum_time_17_19_a_week: long (nullable = false)
 |-- user_clicks_sum_time_19_23_a_week: long (nullable = false)
 |-- user_clicks_sum_time_23_1_a_week: long (nullable = false)
 |-- user_clicks_avg_everyday_weekday: double (nullable = false)
 |-- user_clicks_sum_time_1_9_weekday: long (nullable = false)
 |-- user_clicks_sum_time_9_14_weekday: long (nullable = false)
 |-- user_clicks_sum_time_14_17_weekday: long (nullable = false)
 |-- user_clicks_sum_time_17_19_weekday: long (nullable = false)
 |-- user_clicks_sum_time_19_23_weekday: long (nullable = false)
 |-- user_clicks_sum_time_23_1_weekday: long (nullable = false)
 |-- user_clicks_avg_everyday_weekdend: double (nullable = false)
 |-- user_clicks_sum_time_1_9_weekdend: long (nullable = false)
 |-- user_clicks_sum_time_9_14_weekdend: long (nullable = false)
 |-- user_clicks_sum_time_14_17_weekdend: long (nullable = false)
 |-- user_clicks_sum_time_17_19_weekdend: long (nullable = false)
 |-- user_clicks_sum_time_19_23_weekdend: long (nullable = false)
 |-- user_clicks_sum_time_23_1_weekdend: long (nullable = false)


df_user_clicks_info.select("subscriberid").take(20).foreach(println)


[104752237]
[105517237]
[109901037]
[105246837]
```

It didn't work either :(

Comment: Can you please cast to bigint and then compare ? I guess the datatype may be different on boh dataframes and let me know the result

Comment: @ SadamHussain M, thanks for your advice~ I have tried cast "subscriberid" which in 2 dataframes to long, and it didn't work~ :(

Comment: They are String type columns. Please ensure that there are no spaces before or after the number in any of the dataframes. " 162323641" won't be equal to "162323641" and hence those rows won't join.

Comment: @ Selnay Thanks for your advice~ I checked the column "subscriberid" in 2 dataframes which used  to join, I print it, no space, it didn't work. :(

Comment: Try `val df_tmp_tmp_0 = df_train_raw.join(df_user_clicks_info, df_train_raw("subscriberid")===df_user_clicks_info("subscriberid"))`

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using the latest spark 2.4.4 ?

Comment: @Salim Thanks for your advice~~ : ) I have tried it, it didn't work~ :(  I think this is a bug in SPARK-1.6.0~

Comment: @user238607 Thanks for your advice~~ I think this is a bug in SPARK-1.6.0~ :( And the reason why I didn't use the latest version because the spark in my company sever is this version~ I can't update it ~

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help of friends who helped me. And the reason why for this, I think is a bug in SPARK-1.6.0, I solved it by changing my data process without updating SPARK. I mean in the beginning, I wanted to get df_3 from df_1 and df_2, but it didn't get the result I want because of the bug I mentioned in the question, so I tried another way to get a df_tmp_1 and df_tmp_2, then join them and get the result. I don't know why either, but it seems like a good idea if U use the SPARK-1.6.0 and meet the same join bug like me.